# A question on an answer on Math Overflow about Artin approximation

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question on an answer of this [Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88072/how-to-compute-the-henselization-of-some-simple-rings).

Let $(A,I)$ be a commutative excellent normal local domain. The completion
$$
\hat A=\underset{\longleftarrow}{\operatorname{lim}} A/(I^nA)
$$
has $A$ as a subring by the canonical map. An answer to the referred question on MO states that the *henselization* $A^h$ of $A$ can be defined as the separable closure $S$ of $A$ in $\hat A$. More precisely, an element $a\in \hat A$ is in $A^h$ iff there if a separable polynomial $f\in A[X]$ with $f(a)=0$ (is this interpretation correct?). According to the answers, this should follow from Artin approximation.

> How does this description of $A^h$ follows from Artin approximation? Where do I need the properties ''excellent'' and ''normal''? Where ''separability''?

At least for the (probably easy?) direction $S\subseteq A^h$ there should be an other argument.

To cite a lecture of Popescu,

> a Noetherian local ring $(A,I)$ has the *property of approximation* if
>   every finite system of polynomial equations $f$ over $A$ in
>   $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ has its solutions in $A$ dense with respect to the
>   $I$-adic topology in the set of its solutions in the completion $\hat A$
>   of $A$; that is, for every solution $\hat x$ of $f$ in $\hat A$ and
>   every positive integer $c$ there exists a solution $x$ of $f$ in $A$
>   such that $$x\equiv \hat x\mod I^c\hat A.$$

The Artin approximation theorem is the statement that some rings have this property of approximation. This should be relevant for the question with a single polynomial equation instead of a system. I think one needs ''normality'' and ''excellence'' for the Artin approximation theorem to hold but I can't find it in the literature formulated with these properties. Moreover, I am curious where the separability comes into the game.

Comment: have you tried asking on MathOverflow?

Comment: I am guessing that 'separable' comes from the minimality of the Henselization. The hypothesis of Hensel's lemma (in one of its form) is to have a polynomial with a simple root. Extending by a root that is multiple in its minimal polynomial wouldn't change if Hensel's lemma is satisfied or not. Remember this is just a guess. I am studying these things now and I am precisely trying to understand this question that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If $(R, \mathfrak m)$ is a Noetherian local ring with henselization $R^h$, then the map on completions $R^\wedge \to (R^h)^\wedge$ is an isomorphism, see [Lemma Tag 06LJ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06LJ). Since also $R^h$ is Noetherian (ibid.) we may think of $R^h$ as a subring of its completion (because the completion is faithfully flat in the Noetherian case). In this way we see that we may identify $R^h$ with a subring of $R^\wedge$.

Now we can start to think about which elements of $R^\wedge$ are in $R^h$. For simplicity we assume $R$ is a domain with fraction field $K$. Clearly, every element $f$ of $R^h$ is algebraic over $R$, in the sense that there exists an equation of the form $a_n f^n + \ldots + a_1 f + a_0 = 0$ for some $a_i \in R$ with $n > 0$ and $a_n \not = 0$.

Conversely, assume that $f \in R^\wedge$, $n \in \mathbf{N}$, and $a_0, \ldots, a_n \in R$ with $a_n \not = 0$ such that $a_n f^n + \ldots + a_1 f + a_0 = 0$. OK, now by Artin Approximation if $R$ is a G-ring (slightly weaker than excellent), then, for every $N > 0$ there exists an element $g \in R^h$ with $a_n g^n + \ldots + a_1 g + a_0 = 0$ and $f - g \in \mathfrak m^N R^\wedge$, see [Theorem Tag 07QZ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07QZ). We'd like to conclude that $f = g$ when $N \gg 0$. If this is not true, then we find infinitely many roots $g$ of $P(T)$ in $R^h$. This is impossible because (1) $R^h \subset R^h \otimes_R K$ and (2) $R^h \otimes_R K$ is a finite product of field extensions of $K$. Details omitted.

Conclusion: If $R$ is a local domain with fraction field $K$ and a G-ring, then $R^h \subset R^\wedge$ is the set of all elements which are algebraic over $K$.